# Add two line before a string in a file using awk

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed

I want to add two line

```
allow = alaw
allow = g729
```

before a string

```
nat = no
```

in a file `sip.conf` (or any text based file). If `allow = alaw` and `allow = g729` already exists before `nat = no` it should not be added. This script will run every hour.
And the line should not be added in the two sections immediately after `[general]` and `[providertrunk0]` of the file.

#### Example file content:

```
[general]
disallow = all
allow = ulaw
nat = no

[providertrunk0]
disallow = all
allow = ulaw
;allow = alaw
nat = no

secret =
nat = no
progressinband = yes

allow = ulaw
allow = alaw
nat = no
progressinband = yes

disallow = all
allow = ulaw
allow = g729
nat = no
progressinband = yes
```

#### expected output

```
[general]
disallow = all
allow = ulaw
nat = no

[providertrunk0]
disallow = all
allow = ulaw
;allow = alaw
nat = no

secret =
allow = alaw
allow = g729
nat = no
progressinband = yes

allow = ulaw
allow = alaw
allow = g729
nat = no
progressinband = yes

disallow = all
allow = ulaw
allow = alaw
allow = g729
nat = no
progressinband = yes
```

#### My attempt

`cat addCodec.awk`

```
BEGIN {
    RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; FS=OFS="\n"
    skip["[general]"]
    skip["[providertrunk0]"]
    addCodec = "allow = alaw\nallow = g729"
    tgt = "nat = no"
}
!($1 in skip) {
    for (i=1; i<NF; i++) {
        if ( ($i != addCodec) && ($(i+1) == tgt) ) {
            $i = $i OFS addCodec
        }
    }
}
{ print }
```

```
awk -f addCodec.awk sip.conf
```

this script works if both line does not exist , it will add them.
If a single line exist then I am stuck , what if condition I need to use.

Comment: i'm not specialist in `awk` but as I understand `$i` gives single line but you compare it with string which has two lines `"allow = alaw\nallow = g729"` - so it can't be correct. And maybe you should check separatelly  `$i == tgt && $(i-1) == "allow = g729"` and later `$i == tgt && $(i-2) == "allow = alaw"`

Comment: Is the line `;allow = alaw` **really** supposed to be that in the `[providertrunk0]` block or is the leading `;` a mistake? If it is a mistake then please fix your example.

Comment: no, its not a mistake, I use semicolon to comment out. @EdMorton,

Comment: So you could have lines like that in your other blocks too? So then when looking for `allow = alaw` if `;allow = alaw` is present we should ignore it? If `;allow = alaw` is present in a block where we otherwise want to add it, should we remove or uncomment it or leave it or what?

Comment: Also - what if `allow = alaw` and `allow = g729` exist in the block but there's another line between  them and `nat = no`? What if they exist but there's another line between them? What if they exist after `nat = no` but in the same block. Please [edit] your question to describe how all the different cases should be handled or state if they can't occur, and make sure your sample input/output covers all possible cases.

Comment: because we have to add  allow = alaw ,  we can uncomment. but there will be one line of allow = alaw  that will be uncommented.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111406/discussion-between-addi-jeo-and-ed-morton).

Comment: There's nothing to discuss - just make sure your question covers all your use cases so we can help you come up with a script that covers them all rather than a script that only covers the one sunny day case you've described so far.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not specialist in `awk` (but `python`) but `$i` gives single line and you compare it with string which have two lines `"allow = alaw\nallow = g729"` - and this is problem. You should check every line separatelly.

I created code which check `$(i-1)` and `$(i-2)` and compare separatelly with `"allow = alaw"` (FIRST) and `"allow = g729"`(SECOND). This way I split it into three situations

```
FIRST - exist,  SECOND - missed
FIRST - missed, SECOND - missed
FIRST - missed, SECOND - exist
```

and add different value to `$i` or `$(i-1)`

---

```
BEGIN {
    RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; FS=OFS="\n"
    skip["[general]"]
    skip["[providertrunk0]"]
    addCodec1 = "allow = alaw"
    addCodec2 = "allow = g729"
    tgt = "nat = no"
}
!($1 in skip) {
    for (i=1; i<NF; i++) {
        if ($(i) == tgt) {
            # FIRST - exist, SECOND - missed
            if ( ($(i-1) == addCodec1) ) {
                $i = addCodec2 OFS $i
            }
            # FIRST - missed, SECOND - missed
            else if ( ($(i-1) != addCodec1) && ($(i-1) != addCodec2) ) {
                $i = addCodec1 OFS addCodec2 OFS $i 
            }
            # FIRST - missed, SECOND - exist
            else if ( ($(i-2) != addCodec1) && ($(i-1) == addCodec2)  ) {
                $(i-1) = addCodec1 OFS $(i-1)
            }
        }
    }
}
{ print }
```

---

**BTW:** To make it more unviveral (and simpler) I would run it two times with different arguments.

First to put only `"allow = g729"` before `"nat = no"`, second to put only `"allow = alaw"` before `"allow = g729"`.

This way I could run it again to put `"third line"` befor `"allow = alaw"` and run it again to put `"fourth line"` befor `"third line"`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your existing attempt. The complexity of looking at the various possible scenarios is encapsulated inside a user defined function fx(). Depending on what index the tgt line is found, the various possible scenarios are charted.

```
$ cat addCodec.txt
BEGIN {
    RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; FS=OFS="\n"
    skip["[general]"]
    skip["[providertrunk0]"]
    e1 = "allow = alaw"
    e2 = "allow = g729"
    a[e2] = a[e1] = 1
    addCodec = e1 OFS e2
    tgt = "nat = no"
}
!($1 in skip) {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i "" == tgt) {
          fx(i)
          break
        }
    }
}
{ print }
function fx(i,   cond) {
  cond = (i>2 ? (a[$(i-2)]+0) : 0) "" (i>1 ? (a[$(i-1)]+0) : 0)
  if      ( cond "" == "11" ) { $(i-2) = e1; $(i-1) = e2 }
  else if ( cond "" == "01" ) { $(i-1) = addCodec        }
  else if ( cond    ~  /0$/ ) { $(i) = addCodec OFS $(i) }
}

$ awk -f addCodec.txt file
```